# how to upload files in domain with extension ".tech" using the controlpanel.tech website

Tags: dns, github-pages, custom-domain

i have purchase a domain from the website "get.tech" using my github student developer pack and after purchase it redirect me to controlpanel.tech website to maintain and all. I have already created my portfolio website and hosted it in github. but now in pages when i am trying to add the custom domain and put my domain. it is showing dns error. I have seen some video in youtube and do in that way still i am not able to see my portfolio in my domain name. can anyone help me how we can setup in controlpanel.tech. I am trying for one week but didn't understand what exactly is the problem.

i am getting this error in my github pages when connecting to custom domain
[error snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvcVl.png)